# JAX-WS and SOAP mapping for response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, jax-ws

I have to implements a webservice interface and the following response SOAP message has been provided:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENC:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:NS2="urn:WebserviceIntf">
    <NS1:VoidPaymentResponse xmlns:NS1="urn:WebserviceIntf-Webservice">
      <return href="#1"/>
    </NS1:VoidPaymentResponse>
    <NS2:TVoidPaymentResponse id="1" xsi:type="NS2:TVoidPaymentResponse">
      <MessageCode xsi:type="xsd:string">00</MessageCode>
      <MessageDescription xsi:type="xsd:string">Successful</MessageDescription>
    </NS2:TVoidPaymentResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is what i have for the interface web method.

```
  @WebMethod(operationName = "VoidPayment")
  @ResponseWrapper(targetNamespace = "urn:WebserviceIntf-Webservice")
  @RequestWrapper(targetNamespace = "urn:WebserviceIntf-Webservice")
  public VoidPaymentDetailResponse voidPayment(
          @WebParam(name = "LoginID") String loginId,
          @WebParam(name = "Password") String password,
          @WebParam(name = "TransactionID") String transactionId,
          @WebParam(name = "Echo") String additionalInformation,
          @WebParam(name = "TVoidPaymentResponse", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, targetNamespace = "urn:WebserviceIntf") Holder<VoidPaymentDetail> voidPaymentDetails) {
    VoidPayment vp = new VoidPayment(loginId, password, transactionId, additionalInformation);
    VoidPaymentDetail vpd = voidPayment(vp);
    voidPaymentDetails.value = vpd;
    return new VoidPaymentDetailResponse("#" + vpd.getId());
  }
```

When i test my web method on SOAPUI. I get the following soap message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns3:VoidPaymentResponse xmlns:ns2="http://payapi.afrocoin.com/" xmlns:ns3="urn:WebserviceIntf-Webservice" xmlns:ns4="urn:WebserviceIntf">
         <return href="#Od4dY"/>
         <ns4:TVoidPaymentResponse id="Od4dY">
            <MessageCode>32</MessageCode>
            <MessageDescription>Login failed</MessageDescription>
         </ns4:TVoidPaymentResponse>
      </ns3:VoidPaymentResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Clearly there is a difference between the two messages, and i need to comply fully with the expected response.
What annotations do i need to add to the web method to make sure that this happens.

I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out.

Additional codes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VoidPaymentDetailResponse {

  @XmlAttribute(name = "href")
  private String paymentDetail;

  public VoidPaymentDetailResponse() {
  }

  public VoidPaymentDetailResponse(String paymentDetail) {
    this.paymentDetail = paymentDetail;
  }

  public String getPaymentDetail() {
    return paymentDetail;
  }

  public void setPaymentDetail(String paymentDetail) {
    this.paymentDetail = paymentDetail;
  }

}

@XmlType(name = "TVoidPaymentResponse", namespace = "urn:WebserviceIntf")
@Entity
@Table(name = "VoidPaymentResponseDetails")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class VoidPaymentDetail implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 19383656L;
  @Id
  @XmlTransient
  private Long detailId = IdGenerator.generateId();
  @XmlAttribute
  @XmlID
  @Transient
  private String id = IdGenerator.generateIdentifier(5);
  @XmlElement(name = "MessageCode")
  private String messageCode;
  @XmlElement(name = "MessageDescription")
  private String messageDescription;
  @XmlTransient
  @OneToOne
  private VoidPayment voidPaymentRequest;

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Long getDetailId() {
    return detailId;
  }

  public void setDetailId(Long detailId) {
    this.detailId = detailId;
  }

  public VoidPayment getVoidPaymentRequest() {
    return voidPaymentRequest;
  }

  public void setVoidPaymentRequest(VoidPayment voidPaymentRequest) {
    this.voidPaymentRequest = voidPaymentRequest;
  }

  public String getMessageCode() {
    return messageCode;
  }

  public void setMessageCode(String messageCode) {
    this.messageCode = messageCode;
  }

  public String getMessageDescription() {
    return messageDescription;
  }

  public void setMessageDescription(String messageDescription) {
    this.messageDescription = messageDescription;
  }

}
```

I am using the default jboss wsimport.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Can you publish the wsdl your are importing with the wsimport?

Comment: no, i am the one to generate the wsdl so that the response message complies with the mentioned soap message

Comment: OK, I think I now understand what you are trying to do. You need to expose a webservice and the response that is returned needs to match the response from the first response listed in the question. But the message that you are returning is not the same as the first response.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw exactly

Comment: Does the message context you are trying to clone have a wsdl with the namespaces and everything? This would be the right place to start because you could import that wsdl and you would have the VoidPaymentResponse object already configured with the correct namespace. Otherwise you are going to have to use jaxb and jax-ws annotations.

Comment: No i dont think so because i was informed that they will use the wsdl i provide. Hence i need to use jaxb and jax-ws annotations to ensure that i conform to the message

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do what you want to do. I don't believe you can have two types of objects in the body. "The method response is viewed as a single struct containing an accessor for the return value and each [out] or [in/out] parameter." http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383533 . You can wrap both of the objects an a wrapper but I don't think you can make the response appear as it does in the first message.

Comment: You can provide this as answer, and i will ask the other party about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment. I don't believe that you can replicate the first message. This is because it contains two separate part's in the body.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383533

7.1 RPC and SOAP Body

- A method response is modelled as a struct.
- The method response is viewed as a single struct containing an accessor for the return value and each [out] or [in/out] parameter. The first accessor is the return value followed by the parameters in the same order as in the method signature.

Comment: I think this makes sense. I will accept this as the answer to my problem.